# Получение Id кнопки

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте, уважаемые форумчане.

Есть 2 кнопки:

```
id="play_music" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%;color:       red;"onclick="document.getElementById('player').play();play_song(this);">Воспроизведение<
```

И функция:

```
function play_song(id) {
$(id).css('display','none');
$('#'+$(id).attr('id')+'1').css('display',''); 
}
$('#'+$(id).attr('id')+'1').css('display',''); `в`
```

Здесь `Id` формируется из 3 компонентов, которые соединяются в 1 строку. А можно ли как-нибудь сделать то же самое, только в конце не прибавить '1', а наоборот, удалить последний символ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var elementId = '#'+$(id).attr('id').slice(0,-1);`

Comment: О, спасибо большое - все работает.